# Best way to load a lot of JSON to couchdb

Tags: json, performance, couchdb

I'm using the following command to load json and it works but with small files, when i try to load a file like gb of data it take too long to load it. If anyone need its the following command, it works good with small files.

```
curl -d @test8.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
    http://"credentials"@127.0.0.1:5984/databases/_bulk_docs
```

How can improve the time of loading data?

Comment: Is this for a one-off load, or will you be doing this action frequently?

Comment: its just a work in college, just need to load files one time.